# Handlebars - Error: each doesn't match else

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm trying to inject my MongoDB data to the HTML, but i keep getting this:
"Error: each doesn't match else", I tried to change a few lines but i still getting this error, it's my first project with MongoDB or databases.
What to i need to change in order my code to work? is it HTML or node problem?

HTML

```
{{#each ideas}}
 <div>
   <p>{{tip}}</p>
 </div>
{{/else}}
```

server.js

```
 const path = require('path');
 const express = require('express');
 const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const handlebars = require('handlebars')
 const app = express();


 //map global promise - get rid of warning
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

 // connect to  mongoose
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/peppino-calc', {
   useMongoClient: true
 })
 .then(() => { console.log('MongoDB connected...')})
 .catch(err => console.log(err));

 //Load salaryModel
 require('./modles/Idea.js');
 const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas');



 //handlebars middleware
  app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


  handlebars.registerHelper("toLowerCase", function(input) {
      var output = input.toLowerCase();
      return output.replace(" ", "");
  });


 //body parser middleware
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())


 // post history page
 app.get('/history', (req, res) => {
   Idea.find({})
    .sort({date: 'desc'})
    .then(ideas => {
      res.render('../js/newJs/history', {
        ideas:ideas
      })
    });
 })


  //process form
  app.post('/ideas', (req, res) => {
    let errors = [];
    if(errors.length > 0) {
      console.log(errors[0]);
    } else {
      const newUser = {
        amount: req.body.totalamount,
        hours: req.body.totalhours,
        salary: req.body.totalsalary,
        tip: req.body.totaltip,
        date: req.body.datetotal
      }
      new Idea(newUser)
      .save()
      .then(idea => {
        res.redirect('/history');
      })
    }
  });

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './js/newJs')));
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5700);

  var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('listening on port ', server.address().port);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is from Handlebars, an `#each` iterator should be closed with `/each`

```
{{#each ideas}}
 <div>
   <p>{{tip}}</p>
 </div>
{{/each}}
```

`else` can be used for when there is an empty list, if it is inside the `each` section:

```
{{#each ideas}}
 <div>
   <p>{{tip}}</p>
 </div>
{{else}}
 <div>
   <p>none</p>
 </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you should have fixed this by now, But I want to answer this just for people that might run into this type of error in the future.

Looking at your code, the error is in your HTML file (Handlebars syntax) not server.js.

Your `{{#each}}` iterator should close with `{{/each}}` not `{{/else}}`.

So your code should look like this:

```
{{#each ideas}}

    <div>

     <p>{{tip}}</p>

    </div>

{{else}}

    <div>

     <p>Do nothing</p>

    </div>

{{/each}}
```